# Quick testing tool for context sensitive grammars

Tags: formal-grammars

> Is there a ready-made tool / library that takes as input a **context sensitive** grammar $G$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$, and gives the ability to quickly check if a set of strings $\{w_1, w_2, ..., w_n \}$ belongs to $L(G)$ or not? (and if a string belongs to $L(G)$ outputs the derivation tree)?

...OR ...

> ... in the case there is no such tool, what approach do you suggest ?

What I have in mind is to use a contraint modelling language such as MiniZinc and build a simple "CS grammar to minizinc converter" on top of it; using the derivation length as a parameter to keep the running time feasible on hard cases (for some G the resulting membership problem could even be PSPACE complete) ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software recommendations belong on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @DavidRicherby: ... in the case there is no such tool, what approach do you suggest ? :-)

Comment: Not my area of expertise so sorry but I can't help with that.  That part of your question is on-topic if you're asking about algorithmic approaches and, I'd say, off-topic if you're asking about implementation details. I'd suggest splitting your question in two, with one part on [softwarerecs.se] and one part either here or on [so].

Comment: isnt this (something like) a P-Space complete problem? if so, therefore, no such tool can exist...?